# how i update company info using laravel 5.3.

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

i am trying to update company information. when i get the edit form with already saved previously inputs and after edit the inputs and click on update button its not show any message and not update any information.

Here is edit.blade.php:

```
<form class="form-horizontal company-form" action="/company/edit" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="contact_id" value="{{$company->id}}">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Company Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$company->company_name}}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{$company->email}}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Contact</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="contact" value="{{$company->contact}}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="address"  rows="5">{{$company->address}}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if(Session::has('message'))
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">{{Session::get('message')}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default">Update</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Here is Controller:

```
public function updateInfo(Request $request){
        $company = Company::where('id','=',$request->id);

        $data = [
            'company_name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'contact' => $request->contact,
            'address' => $request->address
        ];

        if($company->update($data)){
            $request->session()->flash('message','Successfully Update Company!!');
                return redirect('/company/edit'.'/'.$request->id);
        }else{
            $request->session()->flash('message','Not Update Company!!');
            return redirect('/company/edit'.'/'.$request->id);
        }
    }
```

Here is Route:

```
    Route::get('/company/edit/{id}','CompanyController@editCompany');
    Route::post('/company/edit/{id}','CompanyController@updateInfo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your update route requires an `id` parameter, but your form is just posting to `/company/edit/` so It will not match any of your routes.

Change the action on your form to include the id.

```
action="/company/edit/{{ $company->id }}"
```